# Keeping personal vimrc and syntax files etc in source control?

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, git

I am trying to create a (git) repository for my vim files. Now, I am already struggling as to what directory I would store my files under. As far as I can see there is either `%HOME%` or `%VIM%`, right? Naturally, I feel more inclined to use `%VIM%`. So I go

```
set VIM=x:\path\to\repo

cd %VIM%

notepad vimrc
```

to create a basic vimrc file in my repo. The `vimrc` also contains `syntax enable`. Now, when I start gvim and the startup process reaches the `syntax enable` line, it gives an error message:

> Error detected while processing x:\path\to\repo\vimrc
>   line 86
>   E484: Can't open file x:\path\to\repo\syntax\syntax.vim

This seems to be because vim automatically sets `$VIMRUNTIME` to the value of `$VIM` if `$VIM` is set. This is of course not what I want, since I was happy with vim's default determining of `$VIMRUNTIME` at startup. Neither do I want to globally set `%VIMRUNTIME%` as I don't want to change it if I install a newer vim version.

So, what is the canonical way to keep my personal vim files in a repository?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GitHub for .vimrc and plugins](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/543/github-for-vimrc-and-plugins)

Comment: Perhaps you want to use forward slashes? i.e. `set VIM=x:/path/to/repo`. I don't have a Windows machine to test, but all the docs use forwards slashes.

Comment: Don't manually set the `VIM` environment variable.  `$VIM` and `$VIMRUNTIME` are automatically set by Vim when it runs.  You should prefer to use `$HOME` since that is your personal config area where as `$VIM` is a system directory, which you may not even have write access to.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since 7.4, all your configuration files (even your vimrc) are expected to be in this directory:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\
```

But the name and location of that directory only matter to Vim. From Git's point of view, that directory could as well be `/etc/foo/bar/` without any impact whatsoever.

So...

1. put your `vimrc` and all your third-party scripts in  `%userprofile%\vimfiles\`,
2. put that directory under version control.

When you need to clone your repo on a unix-like system you do:

```
$ git clone <remote url> ~/.vim
```

or, in git bash on Windows:

```
$ git clone <remote url> $HOME/vimfiles
```

No need to mess with environment variables.

Comment: Minor nitpick: `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` is the location checked first, and I think `%USERPROFILE%` was only added as a fallback in [patch 8.0.1012](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/48340b62e812dc9280f621a2eb6db76d43555c66). I don't know Windows well enough to say whether that means that - as of that patch - `$HOME` will always end up set to `%USERPROFILE%` in practice?

Answer (score 2):

I have a repository called `rc` which contains a `install.sh` script and all my runtime configurations. My workflow is like so:

- On a machine, hack `~/.vimrc` till I am happy with it.
- Copy `~/.vimrc` to `rc/vimrc`.
- Add, commit with a useful message, and push.
- On a different machine: fetch+merge rc.
- Run `install.sh` which takes a backup of the current file and copies the repository one over the current one.

Clearly this works on *nix and not on Windows. However, the method could be easily adapted. How to do this is left as an exercise for the reader<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1. Mostly because I have no idea how to it myself!</sup></sub>

Comment: You might be better off just putting your vimrc in the rc folder and using a symlink for ~/.vimrc, like so: `ln -s ~/rc/vimrc ~/.vimrc`. That way, you don't have to worry about copying it back and forth from ~ and rc.

Comment: @8bittree: That ... That would be indeed better.

Comment: @8bittree Will making a hard link make a difference?

Comment: @MaNyYaCk [Please use dotbot](https://github.com/anishathalye/dotbot) instead. Much better tool.

Comment: @MaNyYaCk I would expect a hard link to work fine, but, as I don't find myself using them very often, it's entirely possibly that they have some behavioral quirk that I'm unaware of that might cause problems.

Comment: @Sardathrion will check out. I accidentally came on this question and I have already implemented something similar to your answer and 8bittree together few days ago. My install script creates hard link so was just asking if it creates any issue.

Answer (score 2):

I put all of my plugins right into the hierarchy, I see the benefits of the various plugin managers but they don't do things that I want... I also locate my Vim configuration hierarchy "remote" from my user directory because it is shared between operating systems (via Bootcamp for instance) and across machines and even in some cases across the network.

On my current machine this is my .vimrc:

```
set runtimepath^=~/Documents/dotfiles/vim
runtime vimrc
```

On a different machine, running Windows, it's similar:

```
set runtimepath^=C:/dotfiles/vim
runtime vimrc
```

And my .gvimrc in both cases just uses `runtime gvimrc`. If this directory is shared on the network I can also happily use (via batch file and to a shared location for the vim runtime too)

```
gvim -u \\my_pc\dotfiles\vim\vimrc -U \\my_pc\dotfiles\vim\gvimrc
```

All of this is in source control of course but if I'm just remoting into a computer sometimes it's easier just to load the config off of my host directly.