# How can I add everything under .vim directory into github?

Tags: git

Hello I blew my MacOSX PC away and started fresh.

I did a `git init` on my laptop's vim directory and installed all the appropriate plugins/bundle using pathogen.

Now my issue is, when I `git add -A` every under .vim and then committed everything and pushed it to **github**.

My problem is NOT everything under **.vim/** directory got commit and pushed up into github. In particular the stuff under the **bundle/** directory (which are the most important things).

The directory themselves under bundle are push to github but they are **all empty**.

How can I add all of them into github without having to go and resort to doing it one by one in each folder? (some of these are already under source control from their original authors).

Is there a better way to do this?

I move around machines a lot sometimes, so it would be handy to know.

Thanks.

Comment: They are not added because those directories are already a repository of their own. The best way that I found for adding the plugins on my git repository is using `submodules`. you may look at this [screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/synchronizing-plugins-with-git-submodules-and-pathogen)

Comment: `gitignore` file maybe? In any case, not really a Vim question... We have [one such question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/543/github-for-vimrc-and-plugins) for general tips & hints on using git with vim init files, if you're having troubles with git, you should ask this on Stack Overflow. I've closed this question rather than migrating it to SO, as it doesn't contain enough information to give a meaningful answer (and would likely be closed on SO). Add some information like the directory structure, output of `git status`, etc. and I can migrate it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker you can close it if you want, I decided to use the submodule method to track them as its seem to be the most efficiency way. Thanks vappolinario, I was watching that screencast before but didn't understand it the first time but now it makes sense.

Comment: Is submodule really the most **efficient** method? What about vim-plug and/or Vundle? (In fact, vim-plug was chosen as the default method for plugin install in neovim, AFAIK)

Comment: @Vitor AFAIK to track it under source control under git using github and without having to maintain those particular plugins across multiple machine. I'm using pathogen for installing them, I'm not using neovim, I'm using standard terminal. When I did a pull from github and submodule init update, it grabs everything it needs and installs the other plugins from their respective repo, keeping my github repo lightweight.