# How to conditionally load plugins

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, plugin-pathogen

I was searching for an answer to this, but haven't found anything yet, so if I missed something obvious, I apologize. I thought it would be a quick google search away, so maybe it's more complicated than I thought.

I'd like to be able to conditionally load plugins based on the type of file I'm editing. For example, when editing python, I don't want the keybindings that `vim-sexp` installs, but when working on clojure, I do want that plugin to be loaded.

I'm currently using neovim and pathogen, but if there's a different plugin manager that does this for me, I'd be open to switching. Also, if this does exist, does `:set syntax whatever` switch the plugins? Because that would be super :)

Thanks in advance for any help/direction!

Comment: You are asking a question, but you actually describe another: if a plugin installs global keybindings, disable them (read the plugin docs about how to do it), and re-enable them locally (using autocmds for example) only for the filetypes you want. If the plugin is well written, you don't gain too much by delaying its initialization. But if you don't disable the unwanted global *keybindings* activated by a plugin, they will still affect you *after* the plugin is loaded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this with Vim-Plug. See [the README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#example):

```
" On-demand loading
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
```

I think you'll have to use `:set filetype whatever` instead of `set syntax whatever` to enable the plugin.

(Some other plugin manager might allow you to do that, see [What is the difference between the vim plugin managers?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841))

Comment: Note the vim-plug maintainers no longer recommend this feature: https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/issues/953#issuecomment-626317600.

Answer (score 9):

Instead of calling `execute pathogen#infect()` to load all plugins, call `pathogen#interpose` for every plugin, i.e.:

```
execute pathogen#interpose('bundle/unicode.vim')
execute pathogen#interpose('bundle/AnsiEsc.vim')
```

The pathogen API isn't documented outside of [the source](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/blob/master/autoload/pathogen.vim), but it's simple enough (even though the function names are obscure and non-descriptive). You can also use `pathogen#surround()`for absolute paths.

You can load plugins conditionally with a basic `autocmd`:

```
" Always use this plugin
execute pathogen#interpose('bundle/unicode.vim')

" Only for Python
autocmd FileType python execute pathogen#interpose('bundle/vim-sexp')
```

If you find you have many of these cases, you could even split it up into different paths:

- `~/.vim/bundle/always` for plugins you always want
- `~/.vim/bundle/<filetype>` for plugins for a  specific filetype
- And then load it like so:

  ```
  " Always use this plugin
  execute pathogen#infect('bundle/always/{}')

  " Load filetype plugins if they exist
  autocmd FileType * if isdirectory('/home/martin/.vim/bundle/' . &ft) | execute pathogen#infect('bundle/' . &ft. '/{}') | endif
  ```

This way you don't have to add a whole bunch of `autocmd`s for every filetype/plugin.

> if this does exist, does `:set syntax whatever` switch the plugins? Because that would be super :)

- Once a plugin is loaded, it's loaded. A "plugin" is simply a collection of `function`, `command`, and `map` definitons. I don't know of any straightforward way to "unload' this.
- It *does* load plugins for a filetype iff you use `:set filetype`; In general, you always want to use `:set filetype` and *not* `:set syntax`, as `syntax` will only set the syntax highlighting, and not the indentation and other settings (e.g. `iskeyword`, `formatexpr`, etc.).