# Unable to get autocmd to execute command

Tags: autocmd

This works:

`execute pathogen#infect('bundle/ruby/{}')`

But this doesn't:

`autocmd FileType * execute pathogen#infect('bundle/ruby/{}')`

Nor this:

`autocmd FileType * :execute pathogen#infect('bundle/ruby/{}')`

Nor about 3 other things I tried.

**UPDATE:** This works:

`autocmd BufWinEnter * execute '!ls'`

But not this:

`autocmd FileType * execute '!ls'`

**UPDATE 2:**

Possibly related: [FileType autocommand not working in Neovim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/22637/filetype-autocommand-not-working-in-neovim)

Comment: Is it Vim or Neovim? Do you even have `filetype on`? Why do you use pathogen at all?

Answer (score 3):

My guess: plugin managers need to be triggered within the scope of `.vimrc` execution.

After that, it's too late, files under `{rtp}/plugin` can't be loaded. And I'm afraid it's the same with file `{rtp}/ftplugin` as they are also triggered by `FileType` **before** your autocommand is triggered.

see `:h starting`-something.

At best the plugin manager you're using has a way to load plugins if some conditions are detected. You'll need to read its documentation in that case. I know a few elaborated plugin managers have this feature.

NB: if the plugin you're trying to use is correctly written: ftplugin files (in your case as I read *"ruby"*) that depends on autoload plugin files, then this should not be a problem: no need to bother with this.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to follow the advice here: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/6961/2021 for pathogen. Maybe it's just bad advice.

Comment: What's really weird is `autocmd BufEnter * execute pathogen#infect('bundle/ruby/ale')`
doesn't work but `autocmd BufEnter * execute '!ls'` does.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Isn't `&rtp` value changed? Updating `'rtp'` is the main purpose of the plugin manager. Loading the "plugins" is and has always been Vim task. plugin files are loaded after `.vimrc` has been loaded, ftplugin files are loaded on opening new buffer of the related filetype, autoload plugin files are loaded on demand.