# Shortcut / abbreviation to insert text block

Tags: vimrc, abbreviations

I'm trying to do something fairly simple. I'm writing latex and I have all these blocks of code, that I'm trying to comment out (and disregard the words in the word count). So I have to write these lines a bazillion times:

```
%TC:ignore
\iffalse
```

and this as well:

```
\fi
%TC:endignore
```

Is it possible to setup a shortcut, so if I type something along the lines of:

```
:zlc[ENTER]
```

it then inserts one of the code-chunks?

Then I could setup my own kind of tailored standard clipboard in my VIMRC-file. So I shouldn't put it all into different registers every time I start Vim.

***Edit1***

Just as I saw the answers, I knew what I had forgotten to search for, which is 'abbreviations'. I would just add it here, so this post would come up, if someone else Googled it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you've got a couple options.

Use an abbreviation:

```
iabbrev zlc %TC:ignore<CR>\iffalse
```

- If you type zlc<kbd>Enter</kbd> in insert mode it will fill in the text.
- `iabbrev` is an abbreviation that only works in insert mode

Use a function:

```
command! Zlc call Ignore()
function! Ignore()
   normal! i%TC:ignore
   normal! o\iffalse
endfunction
```

- If you type `:Zlc`<kbd>Enter</kbd> in normal mode it will fill in the text.
- Note the capital `Z`; user commands cannot start with a lowercase letter.

Place either of these in your `vimrc` to make them work.

See `:h abbrev`, `:h command`, and `:h normal` for more info.

Comment: I didn't get that whole thing about ^M. I'm afraid to edit your answer, since I may just be too dumb to see what you did there. But your answer combined with a tiny bit of Googling about Multi-line Abbreviations gave me the final answer that I was looking for, which is this: iabbrev zlc %TC:ignore\<CR>\iffalse ... Where \<CR> gives you a carriage return. By the way, to those who are thinking 'What the truck is that 'i' doing in front of abbrev (in iabbrev), then I can reveal to you that it is an abbreviation that is only valid in 'Insert mode' (I found that by reading a bit in :help abbrev ).

Comment: The `^M` is a raw carriage return. Your `\<CR>` should work just fine, but you can get `^M` by going into insert mode and then pressing CTRL-V+Enter. It's one character but it is represented by `^M`.

Comment: Edited to remove confusing `^M`s.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you were asking but as @Tumber41 already gave you a solution, here is a possible alternative just to show that you can achieve things in different ways with vim:

```
function! AddCommentLines() range
    call append(a:firstline-1, "%tc:ignore")
    call append(a:firstline, "\iffalse")


    call append(a:lastline+2, "\\fi")
    call append(a:lastline+3, "%tc:endignore")
endfunction

vnoremap <key> :call AddCommentLines()<cr>
```

This function will add the lines around a visual selection. So you can visually select the text you want to comment, press the key combination you'll have defined in the `vnoremap` line and your comments will appears around the selection.

You can also call it directly with a range: say you want to comment lines 100 to 110:

```
:100,110call AddCommentLines()
```

And if you don't provide a range only the current line will be surrounded by the comments.

---

Also I would recommend to try using some snippets [see this question to choose a snippet engine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841). For example with Ultisnips you could add theses lines in the latex snippets file:

```
snippet com "Add opening comment block"
%TC:ignore
\iffalse
endsnippet

snippet ccom "Add closing comment block"
\fi
%TC:endignore
endsnippet
```

This way when you'll type `com` followed by the key you choose to trigger a comment the first comment block will be added. And when you type `ecom` followed by the snippet trigger key the second block will be added.