# How to generate closing tags for HTML?

Tags: vimscript, filetype-html, text-generation

I want to do the following:

When I insert an HTML tag (which is a sequence of text that starts with `<tagname tag_attributes` and ends with `>`), as soon as I press <kbd>></kbd> to insert the `>` character, I want:

1. A text `</tagname>` to be inserted two lines under the current line.
2. Put the cursor on the line which is between the opening and closing tags.
3. Insert a tab.

So, when I insert a text such as `<div possibly_attributes` and insert `>`, I want the following:

```
<div possibly_attributes>
    [cursor here]
</div>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: As others pointed *emmet-vim* is a tool you should definitely try. You write `div#main` and you get the full html - `<div id="main"></div>`.

Answer (score 13):

Here is a simple *ad-hoc* solution to put in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
inoremap <buffer> > ></<C-x><C-o><C-y><C-o>%<CR><C-o>O
```

Breakdown:

```
></                insert '></'
<C-x><C-o><C-y>    use the built-in omni-completion to finish the closing tag
<C-o>%             move the cursor to the beginning of your closing tag
<CR>               insert a newline to push the closing tag on its own line
<C-o>O             open a new line above the current line
```

And here is how it looks like in practice:

[image: imap]

But you should definitely take a look at plugins like [Sparkup](https://github.com/rstacruz/sparkup)/[Emmet](https://github.com/mattn/emmet-vim), that let you use a concise CSS-like notation to produce proper HTML, or [Snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)/[Ultisnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) that let you create and expand very powerful snippets for any language.

--- edit ---

Using Vim productively will be *very hard* without the following lines in your `vimrc`:

```
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set hidden
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

The solution above is guaranteed to work with that minimal setup.

--- endedit ---

Comment: I couldn't get this working. Do I need to press another thing as well after I press `>`?

Comment: No. The right hand side is executed when you press `>`. It should work with a very minimal `vimrc`.

Comment: So do I need to put something in `.vimrc` as well? I have put the plugin in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Maybe a config issue… see my edit.

Comment: Still not working. Is `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/` the correct place? Also, I have tried putting `inoremap <buffer> > ></<C-x><C-o><C-y><C-o>%<CR><C-o>O` to my `.vimrc`. This time it did something but it stopped after inserting `</` and said `E764: Option 'omnifunc' is not set`.

Comment: I am using the system's clipboard as the yank buffer. Can this be the issue?

Comment: `E764` happens either because you don't have `ftplugin indent on` in your `vimrc` or because the buffer is not recognized as html. And yes, `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim` is the right place.

Comment: I put `ftplugin indent on` to my `.vimrc` but vim says: `Error detected while processing .vimrc: E492: Not an editor command: ftplugin indent on`.

Comment: Finally got it working. I have realized that the file name must end with `.html` :-) However although the cursor is being placed on the empty line between the opening and closing tags, a tab is not being inserted, even though I have included the lines suggested in your edit to my `.vimrc`.

Comment: Unrelated: Can you please share how to generate such gif?

Comment: @balki, I use [Licecap](http://www.cockos.com/licecap/) on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 5):

## See [`vim-closetag`](https://github.com/alvan/vim-closetag)

It's exactly what you're looking for. From it's README:

> If this is the current content:
>
> ```
> <table|
> ```
>
> Now you press <kbd>></kbd>, the content will be:
>
> ```
> <table>|</table>
> ```
>
> And now if you press <kbd>></kbd> again, the content will be:
>
> ```
> <table>
>    |
> </table>
> ```

---

*Note: `|` is the cursor here*

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer** This is not directly what you want but I think it can be worth it to mention it here.

If you are ready to use an additional plugin, you could try to use a [snippet engine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841).

For example, Utlisnips comes with a lot of [html snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/html.snippets). For example, you can simply write `div`, press the key configured to trigger a snippet extension and you'll get the structure you're looking for.

Here are some (not all) of the snippets available. Note that you can easily add the ones you want:

```
- DocType XHTML 1.1
- HTML - 5.0 (doctype)
- IE Conditional Comment: Internet Explorer
- IE Conditional Comment: NOT Internet Explorer
- Input with Label
- Select Box
- XHTML   <textarea>
- XHTML <a mailto: >
- XHTML <base>
- <body>
- <div>
- <div> with class
- <div> with ID & class
- XHTML <form>
- XHTML <h1>
- XHTML <link>
- XHTML <meta>
- XHTML <script src...>
- XHTML <script>
- <span>
- <span> with class
- <span> with ID & class
- XHTML <style>
- XHTML <table>
- Link
- paragraph
- list item
- unordered list
- table cell
- table header
- table row
```

---

If a snippet plugin is overkill but you are still okay to use a plugin you can also try the [emmet plugin](http://mattn.github.io/emmet-vim/) which provides a syntax to shortcut your HTML/CSS and expand it easily.

You can see how it works [here](https://asciinema.org/api/asciicasts/4568?)

Answer (score 1):

The old and venerable [closetag plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=12) automatically determines the current HTML / XML tag, and inserts a proper closing tag. It is triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>_</kbd> by default.

I would not recommend automatic insertion; that's probably causing more problems than it solves. But this insert-mode mapping might help:

```
:imap > ><C-_><C-o>F<lt>
```

Answer (score 1):

This plugin [html.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1397) helps me a lot when editing html/xml files. The only thing you should do is save your currently edited file with .html extension.

Comment: Not necessarry to use the html extention. What if I'm using the twig template engine and want my files to end in `.twig`? *It's **set filetype**  that's important here*.