# How can I insert a character repeatedly until even with next line?

Tags: insert-mode, repeated-commands

Say I have a comment like this:

```
//This is a comment
```

And I want to make it like this:

```
//*****************
//This is a comment
//*****************
```

Is there an easy way to insert a character repeatedly until even with the next/previous line?

Comment: To generate patterns like this you might want to use a snippet engine. You can read [this question](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841) for a comparison of the snippets plugins. For example with ultisnips you could do `ibox<key>This is a comment` (where <key> is a key you define to trigger snippets) and that will create a box of the right size with `this is a comment` inside.

Comment: (`17a*<Esc>` would be something you could use In a similar situation where you know the number of characters you need, or the exact number doesn't matter because it doesn't have to be evenly aligned with another line.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Short answer

<kbd>v</kbd>
 
<kbd>$</kbd>
 
<kbd>r</kbd>

<kbd>`*`</kbd>

[`:help v_r`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_r)

## Longer answer

<kbd>y</kbd>

<kbd>y</kbd>


<kbd>p</kbd>
/
<kbd>P</kbd>
     Duplicate line to below/above

<kbd>2</kbd>

<kbd>l</kbd>
                    Move to position from where to overwrite (in this case 3rd column ← 2 to the right)

<kbd>v</kbd>
 
<kbd>$</kbd>
                  Select till end of line

<kbd>r</kbd>
                          [Replace all selected characters by char…](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#v_r)

<kbd>*</kbd>

Comment: **Addition to top voted answer** Don't forget to use `.` to repeat the pattern on the other line!
If you copy the line above and below, use `v$r*` on one of the lines, navigate to the other and press `.` (don't have enough rep for a comment)

Comment: @Niels or duplicate the first overwritten line with `yyjp`

Answer (score 3):

At the occasion°:

## Insert mode mappings to replicate the remainder of adjacent line

```
" Insert the rest of the line below the cursor.
" Mnemonic: Elevate characters from below line
:inoremap <A-e> 
    \<Esc>
    \jl
        \y$
    \hk
        \p
        \a
" Insert the rest of the line above the cursor.
" Mnemonic:  Y depicts a funnel, through which the above line's characters pour onto the current line.
:inoremap <A-y> 
    \<Esc>
    \kl
        \y$
    \hj
        \p
        \a
```

---

## Copying single characters from neighboring lines in Insert mode

… is built-in: [`:help i_CTRL-E`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-E):

> ```
> CTRL-E   Insert the character which is below the cursor.
> CTRL-Y   Insert the character which is above the cursor.
> ```

---

<sub>° Not what the question text was about, but what other users might be looking for here, going from the current question title "insert until even with next line".</sub>

Comment: Are there similar keys for copying character from neighboring cells left/right?

Comment: @Moberg Not equally short ones built-in.  In **Normal mode**, you can do `ylP` to duplicate the char the cursor is on; and `yhp` to duplicate the one to the left.  You can add a count before the `p`/`P`.          You could put for example the following **mappings for Insert mode** in your vimrc: `:inoremap <A-l>  <Esc>lylPi|:inoremap <A-h>  <Esc>ylpa`           (By the way, in Normal mode, you can flip chars with `xp`)