# Macros behaving unexpectedly (not executing commands)

Tags: macro, repeated-commands

I have the following macro

```
let @f='ivoid function (void param^[o  {^M^M^[3kwi'
```

where `^[` represents ESC and `^M` new line.

for some reason it does not execute anything after the `3k`, I tried replacing the `^[` with a `^O` which represents CTRL-O, but instead this made the macro paste some weird text at the end that seemed to come from the help page.

This macro is defined in `~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim`

Comment: you might want to have a look at `:help startinsert`

Comment: I just tried your macro on my machine and it works properly. The first thing you should do is try to start vim without a `.vimrc` (`vim -U NONE)` and see if it works. If it works the problem comes from a setting in your `.vimrc` and you can debug that using [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/1841). Also to do what you want I would prefer using a snippet than a macro, I use UltiSnips but you can read [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841) to choose the snippet manager which fits your need.