# How can I make $ in LaTeX insert \( and \) automatically?

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex

I'm writing a lot of LaTeX recently, and am used to hitting the `$` key for inline math, but have heard that `\(` and `\)` is better (apparently it confuses vim less, especially with `$$`, which I'm also not using).

However, `\(` and `\)` are hard to type quickly—`$` is effectively one keystroke. Can I make `$` insert the appropriate opening and closing brackets at once?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can.

The preliminaries: we will need to determine if the last opening `\(` comes before or after the last closing `\)` in order to determine which delimiter to insert. (This also means we don't have a literal mapping—we are going to use `<expr>` instead.) So I created `~/.vim/autoload/pos.vim` with the following contents:

```
" true iff p1 is before p2 in the buffer
" a pos is [lnum, col]
function! pos#before(p1, p2) abort
  return a:p1[0] < a:p2[0] || (a:p1[0] == a:p2[0] && a:p1[1] <= a:p2[1])
endfunction
```

Then, we need to write our function to return the correct delimiter. In `~/.vim/autoload/tex.vim`:

```
function! tex#inline() abort
  let l:open_pattern = '\m\\('
  let l:close_pattern = '\m\\)'
  let l:open_pos = searchpos(l:open_pattern, 'bn')
  let l:close_pos = searchpos(l:close_pattern, 'bn')
  if pos#before(l:open_pos, l:close_pos)
    return '\('
  else
    return '\)'
  endif
endfunction
```

Finally, we want this to take effect. In `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

```
inoremap <buffer> <expr> $ tex#inline()
```

(Make sure to add the unmapping of `$` to `b:undo_ftplugin` by whatever mechanism you use.)

Comment: Note that this is the kind of use case which fits pretty well a [snippet engine](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841). And as a snippet engine might be a bit overkill for only one snippet I would have tried an abbreviation like this one: `inoremap <buffer> $ \(\)<left><left>`

Comment: @statox agreed; I’m not a big fan of snippets (yet? We shall see...). But I prefer to type the delimiters myself.