# TeX file, search outside math

Tags: filetype-tex, plugin-vimtex

Well, the question is clear. I want to search only on text that is not inside \[  \] or $ $ .

Is there some readymade code to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: You could potentially remap `n` and `N` to keep going if they land on element in one of these; [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/20427/10604) and the one it's a dupe of have some tips on detecting this