# Code snippet completion for vim in C++

Tags: autocompletion

I have YouCompleteMe installed; however that only complete certain words or phrases.  I am looking for something similar in VSCode or Emacs' Yasnippet. For example, if I type `if`, then press `Tab`, then a snippet of the `if` statement would get inserted like this:

```
if($1){
  $2
}
```

where $1 and $2 are my cursor placeholders.  I navigate between them with `Tab`.  Is there anything like this for vim?

Comment: Try ultisnips. It does what you want and much more. Also it had good integration with YouCompleteMe. https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All [snippets plugins](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins) provide this feature. [COC.nvim](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim) provides contextualized completion + snippets (given you've installed and configured a LSP server and a subplugin for snippets). My [lh-cpp plugin](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) provides [idiomatic C++ snippets and wizards](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp/blob/master/doc/snippets.md) (through mu-template)...