# Is there any snippet generator available for vim?

Tags: neovim, snippets, vim8

In vscode/atom/sublime there is a snippet generator. https://snippet-generator.app/
Likewise any snippet generator or plugin to generate present in vim? Can I store snippet in my project github and refer from it?

Comment: You couldn't find anything with Google? Here, I'll make it even easier. Go to  [Vim Awesome](https://vimawesome.com/) and type _snippets_ in the search bar.

Comment: Related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/10604