# Inserting abbreviation from file

Tags: indentation, insert-mode, abbreviations

First, I apologize if this is a trivial question.

I have the following file (`main.ab`) defining a Python snippet:

```python
def main(args):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = ...
    main(args)
```

And in `ftplugin/python.vim` I defined

```
iabbrev <expr> main join(readfile($HOME . "/.vim/ftplugin/main.ab"), "\n")
```

which results in a badly indented output:

```python
def main(args):
        ...

        if __name__ == '__main__':
                args = ...
                    main(args)
```

although executing `:echo join(readfile($HOME . "/.vim/ftplugin/main.ab"), "\n")` results in:

```
def main(args):
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = ...
    main(args)
```

How should I correctly insert the file contents when expanding an abbreviation?

I assume this is related to `PASTE` mode, but I don't see an immediate solution. Is there an alternative to `join(readfile(...))`?

Comment: More likely is related to an iabbrev or expr behaving as if you typed the expansion. You could theoretically instead use the expression register with control-r or control-o :put to bypass the indenting?

Comment: Another solution which is adds more dependencies but might be worth it if you want to create several snippets like this is to use a snippet plugin (see [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7466/1841)). Also if it's just to create repeatable `main` snippets reading [`:h skeleton`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#skeleton) might be interesting.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble - I tried to save the file contents into `=` and then paste from it: `iabbrev <expr> main <c-r>=join(readfile($HOME . "/.vim/ftplugin/main.ab"), "\n")<CR>:put =<CR>`, but I am getting the "invalid expression" error. Do you mean to bypass `iabbrev` entirely?

Comment: @statox - I simply want to be able to paste file contents (i.e. snippets) triggered by the abbreviation keyword. I want to avoid external plugins, if possible.

Comment: I think you would want `iabbrev main <C-r>=join(…)<CR>` or `iabbrev main <C-o>:put =join(…)<CR>`, but I’m not in front of a kbd to test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [D. Ben Knoble](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/10604/d-ben-knoble) I ended up using:

```
iabbrev <silent> main <C-O>:put! =join(readfile(...), \"\n\")<CR><esc>A
```

last `<esc>A` is needed in order to account for the extra space that abbrev inserts.

---

**Edit** (thanks to [filbranden](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/18609/filbranden)) - removing `join()`:

```
iabbrev <silent> main <C-O>:put! =readfile(...)<CR><esc>A
```

Comment: You don't need the explicit `join()`, when `put! =...` gets a list it adds one item per line already. There's also `:r` (short for `:read`) to read the file directly (would spare you the `readfile()`) but it might take some extra steps to read the contents before the current line, so maybe `:put! =...` is more straightforward anyways...