# How to get the filename where the line of vimscript/lua is in?

Tags: neovim, lua

As title. Say I have a line to create an augroup located in file `git.lua`. What I want to achieve is that that line will always create an augroup named `git.lua` without hard-coding it by the string "git.lua", so I can renamed the file and no code needs to change. I did try calling nvim API like `vim.fn.bufname`(and removing the prefix to get `git.lua`) in `git.lua`, but this resulted in an augroup of name `plugins.lua`, since this is where `git.lua` got imported/`require`d. So what's the correct way to achieve this?

In short: I want to have a line of code to create an augroup, such that I can renamed that file and that line will always create an augroup as per the new name.

Comment: Hi @job_start, I believe a small example would help to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt I just re-wrote it completely.

Comment: What snippet engine are you using? All of them should be able to expand the result of `expand('%')`. See `:h expand()` for the filename modifiers.

Comment: @LucHermitte Not sure about the first question. I did try `expand('%:t')` but even if I put it in `git.lua` it created a augroup called `plugins.lua`, which is the file that imports `git.lua`. I want to create an augroup called `git.lua`.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are looking for abbreviations/snippets that use the name of the current file. While abbreviations do the work, snippets are much easier to maintain. There exist plenty dedicated plugins: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins

Comment: @LucHermitte: I didn't mean that. I meant when I call `:au` it should show some autocmd belonging to `git.lua`, not `plugins.lua`. Putting `expand('%:t')` in different files still resulting in a single `git.lua` augroup, which is not what I want...

Comment: @LucHermitte I just made a temporary answer assuming what I really want to do cannot be achieved. Maybe it could make you understand my OP.

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/23.html

Comment: Sorry I've completely misundertstood what you were trying to accomplish. Beside I exclusively program vim in vimscript language. In pure old fashioned and portable (?) way, we can obtain the name of the current file with `let s:sname = expand('<sfile>:t')`. It has to be done at global file level. Not within a function! I leave plugin developers for nvim give you a nvim answer.

Comment: Aren't you looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21417614/15934 ?

Comment: I second the usage of `expand(<sfile>:t')` that should give you the name of the script which you can then use later on.

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of the comments:

```
vim.fn.expand('<sfile>:p')
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that hard-coding the filename for each file is the simplest way to achieve what you want to do. So the code is:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_create_augroup('LSP.lua', { clear = true })

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('CursorHold', {
  group = 'LSP.lua',
  pattern = '*',
...
```

That is: you cannot replace `xxx.lua` with `vim.fn.expand('%:t')`.

Here is an example of some state-of-the-art nvim-v0.9 plugin using the same method: https://github.com/akinsho/bufferline.nvim/blob/e70be6232f632d16d2412b1faf85554285036278/lua/bufferline.lua#L34