# Why should I use either dein.vim or vim-plug?

Tags: plugin-managers

I want to install a plugin manager for vim, and after searching a bit, I saw that plugin managers for vim have evolved since last time I used one (e.g. neobundle is discontinued, etc.); and I also discovered two new ones: dein.vim and vim-plug.

Since they are both new to me, I don't know which one to chose. I enjoy simple and minimal software so I think of going for dein.vim, but it seems that vim-plug is quite popular.

So here's the question: why should I go for either?

*Edit: I have seen the question tagged as "duplicate" before writing this very question, and decided to still ask it because it doesn't treat the case of dein.vim, which appears to be a very interesting alternative. Therefore I don't consider this question to be duplicate, and am still interested in knowing the answer.*

Comment: Try them and decide for yourself. Or keep using whatever you used before.

Comment: What I used before is no longer maintained; and trying then deciding for myself was the plan anyway, however some users here could have more experience than I using them, and may point relevant facts I didn't notice (yet?).

Comment: As an answer to your edit: The original question lacks of an answer about dein.vim that's true but this is still a duplicate: answering your question would only dispatch the knowledge and make it less accessible for other users. Now you should consider reading the doc, trying it and adding your own answer that would be very valuable to the site.

Comment: understood. Now I understand better why this is marked as duplicate. I'm sorry I opened this question, in the light of what you just wrote, it was a mistake. But now I know better, thanks.

Comment: No need to be sorry don't worry. Also I see you're a new user so welcome and don't hesitate to ask other questions when you'll need it :-)

Comment: For the record, I came here looking for an answer to this exact comparison (with all the same intentions of using both, etc). I came here after reading the linked duplicate actually, because nowhere in the duplicate is Dein mentioned. I would've preferred to allow this question to be answered, then later merged with the other. As it stands, marking this as duplicate wasn't helpful to me in this instance.

Comment: WTF is "dark-powered"? I know Shougo develops a lot of plugins, and that their English isn't that great, but an explanation of that would be a minimal requirement of documentation.

Comment: 7heo.tk, both managers are parellel/async so the performance is going to be a lot better than the other ones. However, vim-plug's async feature can only be used in neovim while dein.vim use Shougo's own async dll library so it can run in vim as well. At the end of the day, they are basically the same. Hope this helps

Comment: @Red2awn doesn't [vim-plug's README](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#pros) say that async works in Vim if Ruby or Python is available?

Comment: Yes you are right, it does support asynchronous in Vim. Anyway, I tried dein.vim yesterday and it is not the most user friendly plugin manager. So I would recommend Vim-Plug.

Comment: @7heo.tk: I tested dein.vim to add [an answer](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7886/1841) to the original question. I hope that will be useful to you. If you see things to add, don't hesitate to edit my answer :-)