# What is the Vim8 package feature and how should I use it?

Tags: plugin-system, vim8

Vim 8 was released [today](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.0.0000) and the [release notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim/vim/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt) mentions a new "package" feature. What is it and how should I use it?

Most importantly, does it replace the good old [plugin managers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841)?

Comment: Anyone interested in contributing an answer, might want to take the approach of "most plugins will have instructions for using Pathogen, here's how you translate those instruction to the native package manager". If I figure it out, I'' come back and an answer. Until then the answer by @klaus https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/18526/10672 is an underrated stand in. ❤️ this community!

Answer (score 110, accepted):

First of all, the relevant documentation can be found with [`:h packages`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#packages) on the newly compiled Vim8 version and [here on Github](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/856c1110c1cf0d6e44e387b70732/runtime/doc/repeat.txt#L525).

A first important note is about the vocabulary: In Vim8 a package is defined like this:

> A Vim package is a directory that contains one or more plugins.

This means that the new package manager was created to help users manage all of their plugins in the same archive. The doc lists the following advantages:

> - A package can be downloaded as an archive and unpacked in its own directory.
>   Thus the files are not mixed with files of other plugins.  That makes it
>   easy to update and remove.
> - A package can be a git, mercurial, etc. repository.  That makes it really
>   easy to update.
> - A package can contain multiple plugins that depend on each other.
> - A package can contain plugins that are automatically loaded on startup and
>   ones that are only loaded when needed with `:packadd`.

So the idea is to create a folder containing all of the plugins with the following structure:

```
$HOME/.vim/pack/my-plugins/
                        start/
                            foo/
                                plugin/
                                    foo.vim
                                syntax/
                                    some.vim
                            bar/
                                plugin/
                                    bar.vim
                        opt/
                            buzz/
                                plugin/
                                    buzz.vim
```

The emplacement of the folder is defined by the option `packpath` (See [`:h 'packpath'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27packpath%27)).

Note the importance of the structure of your folder:

- The `start` folder contains plugins which will be loaded automatically on startup.
- The `opt` folder contains "optional" plugins, loaded with the `packadd` command.
- The subfolders (`plugin`, `autoload`, `doc`,...) are the ones you're used to in the plugins.

Here is a recap of the folders:

```
start/foobar/plugin/foo.vim     " always loaded, defines commands
start/foobar/plugin/bar.vim     " always loaded, defines commands
start/foobar/autoload/foo.vim   " loaded when foo command used
start/foobar/doc/foo.txt        " help for foo.vim
start/foobar/doc/tags           " help tags
opt/fooextra/plugin/extra.vim   " optional plugin, defines commands
opt/fooextra/autoload/extra.vim " loaded when extra command used
opt/fooextra/doc/extra.txt      " help for extra.vim
opt/fooextra/doc/tags           " help tags
```

Once these files are in the right place, opening Vim will load the plugins in `start` and make the ones in `opt` available with `:packadd`.

---

Now, can this feature replace the existing plugin managers?

**Disclaimer:** This part may be a little bit opinionated.

I think the approach of this new package manager is really different than the one of the plugins managers we were used to because it is made to manage one (or several) archive(s) containing some plugins.

Out of the box, the package manager doesn't provide features to update your plugins one-by-one, to fetch them automatically from a Github address or to select the plugins you want to enable/disable.

I'm not sure it will be really convenient to use it out of the box (especially because handling nested version control repositories can be a painful task) but maybe this is the occasion to make plugin managers more efficient?

Now it is also possible to imagine moving the existing plugins to adopt the structure required by the package manager and to manage them directly from the file system. Maybe some wrapper will be created to use this new feature.

---

**EDIT** As suggested by @Sato Katsura here is a note about the `helptags` command. The Vim8 commit introduced two line in the [`helptag` doc](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/helphelp.txt#L200-L201):

> ```
> :helpt[ags] [++t] {dir}
>
> Generate the help tags file(s) for directory {dir}.
> When {dir} is ALL then all "doc" directories in 'runtimepath' will be used.
> ```

Which means that the new package manager ease the generation of the helptags put in the user archive. With the single command `:helptags ALL` all the helptags are generated.

Comment: Good summary.  The `package` feature is meant to finally put an end to vimballs and the related dinosaurs, not to compete with the modern plugin managers.  It's a viable replacement for `pathogen`, provided that you don't rely on `pathogen`'s more obscure features.  It makes no attempt to replace, say, `Vundle`.  The concept of package as a collection of plugins is well thought-out and potentially useful, but I fear nobody will use it because the modern plugin managers don't support it.  And plugin managers won't support it because nobody uses it.  It's a bit of a chicken-and-egg problem.

Comment: Unrelated: you might want to add a note about `:helptags ALL`.

Comment: @Sato thanks for the note about the vimballs: as I never use them I didn't even though about it but now that you mention it it seems pretty obvious. I agree with you about the "nobody will use it" note I'm not really optimistic about that. For the `:helptag ALL` I'll have a look and add it, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I moved the [off-topic discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45291/discussion-on-answer-by-statox-what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i).

Comment: [minpac](https://github.com/k-takata/minpac) is a new package manager for Vim 8 (and NeoVim). It builds on top of Vim 8's packages, providing commands to `update` your plugins or `clean` them (removing unused plugins). For bonus points, it also uses the new job control feature to perform multiple updates in parallel. I think it's really promising, because it enhances the built-in packages with a better UX.

Comment: Please check the second link in the answer.

Comment: Thanks @DKBose that is fixed

Answer (score 23):

The answer provided by @statox is very descriptive, but for a new user that can be overwhelming. Instead I want to outline what you need to do in step-by-step pointers.

1. Create `pack/*/start` directory under any of the directories provided by `set packpath`. I did in `~/.config/nvim/pack/*/start`. **Note** that you can use any directory name you want in place of `*` but you can't omit it totally. For example, you can use directory `~/.config/nvim/pack/foo/start` or `~/.config/nvim/pack/bar/start` but not `~/.config/nvim/pack/start`.
2. Go to the `pack/*/start` directory and clone the package there.
3. Fire up n/vim and do `:scriptnames` to check if everything is loaded. Don't worry if not every part is loaded, because some files are meant to loaded after some hook, e.g. `autoload/plugin.vim`.
4. To uninstall, just remove the directory where you cloned the package. Don't need to do anything else.
5. Do `:helptags ALL` to generate tags for all the help docs. Do `:helptags {dir}` for generating tags for the help docs under directory `dir`. For example, if you put your plugin in `~/.config/nvim/pack/foo/plugin_name`, then do `:helptags ~/.config/nvim/pack/foo/plugin_name/doc`. That will generate a `tags` file in the doc directory of the plugin. If you remove the plugin from the directory, the tags file will be gone and vim will not find the help file, so you don't need to uninstall the doc file manually.

Comment: upvote for including mention of :scriptnames

Comment: You can do `:filter /\~/ scriptnames` to filter out default plugins.

Comment: **Not just for "new users":** This is a great instruction set for people who have been using a plugin manager for many years and find themselves in that "new computer" opportunity to clean things up a bit.

Answer (score 15):

To expand on the "can it replace plugin managers",

I used to use Vundle, which was fantastic, but now have replaced it with 18 or so lines of bash.

I find it useful to use subfolders in the pack directory to group related plugins. E.g. "Syntax" or "Ruby".

The relevant bash example is below. Place in a file and run it.

Additional discussion around the topic at: https://stories.abletech.nz/get-rid-of-your-vim-plugin-manager-7c8ff742f643#.abnjauzgk

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# This file lives in ~/.vim/pack/install.sh
# Remember to add executable: chmod +x ~/.vim/pack/install.sh
#
# Create new folder in ~/.vim/pack that contains a start folder and cd into it.
#
# Arguments:
#   package_group, a string folder name to create and change into.
#
# Examples:
#   set_group syntax-highlighting
#
function set_group () {
  package_group=$1
  path="$HOME/.vim/pack/$package_group/start"
  mkdir -p "$path"
  cd "$path" || exit
}
# Clone or update a git repo in the current directory.
#
# Arguments:
#   repo_url, a URL to the git repo.
#
# Examples:
#   package https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise.git
#
function package () {
  repo_url=$1
  expected_repo=$(basename "$repo_url" .git)
  if [ -d "$expected_repo" ]; then
    cd "$expected_repo" || exit
    result=$(git pull --force)
    echo "$expected_repo: $result"
  else
    echo "$expected_repo: Installing..."
    git clone -q "$repo_url"
  fi
}
(
set_group ruby
package https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails.git &
package https://github.com/tpope/vim-rake.git &
package https://github.com/tpope/vim-bundler.git &
package https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise.git &
wait
) &
(
set_group syntax
package https://github.com/kchmck/vim-coffee-script.git &
package https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown.git &
package https://github.com/ap/vim-css-color.git &
wait
) &
(
set_group colorschemes
package https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized.git &
wait
) &
wait
```

Comment: this is excellent

Comment: Update does not work when there is more than one package in group. The second package is reinstalled inside another package. Code must be corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The new format can be thought of as a Pathogen equivalent so there's still space for a manager that can download the plugins you want. There's a few new plugin managers who leverage this new pack format but I still made [Vire](https://github.com/genotrance/vire) since they leave the headache of managing the `vimrc` to you. If you have multiple machines and want the same config across, Vire makes it super easy.

Comment: If you have multiple WINDOWS machines and want the same config ...  FTFY