# How to install a colorscheme with a plugin manager

Tags: plugin-system, installing

I was wondering if someone could assist me in installing a color scheme for VIM? I literally have spent all day yesterday and this morning trying to figure it out. I am using a shell-client (ubuntu) to access my school's unix server. I have a very general idea of how to work in a shell but it is still new to me.

I will post a link to what I am trying to install and thank you in advance for your assistance:

https://github.com/whatyouhide/vim-gotham

Comment: Welcome on our site! We have a question about [how to install a plugin](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/613/1841), [a question about the different existing plugin managers](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841), [a question about the new package manager of vim8](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9522/1841) and of course the doc [`:h plugin`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_05.html#plugin). I think that we have enough resources to say that your question is a duplicate. If you encounter problems while following the information of these resources you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicated question - it seems colorschemes don't work the same way as the usual plugins.

Answer (score 1):

Colors are easy to customize in VIM.

Download your file into the folder in the vim hierarchy `colors`
as (using your example)

```
vim-gotham.vim
```

Add an entry in your vimrc or gvimrc file similar to:

```
source $VIM\vimfiles\colors\vim-gotham.vim
```

I placed the source command as the last entry in mine.