# E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command: Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator' , { 'branch': 'stable'}

Tags: vimrc, plugin-you-complete-me

I have the following `vimrc` file :

```
syntax on
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 1 && line("'\"") <= line("$") | exe "normal! g'\"" | endif
endif


if &compatible
  set nocompatible               " Be iMproved
endif

set runtimepath+=/home/mohsen/.vim/bundle/neobundle.vim/

call neobundle#begin(expand('/home/mohsen/.vim/bundle'))

NeoBundleFetch 'Shougo/neobundle.vim'

NeoBundle 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet.vim'
NeoBundle 'Shougo/neosnippet-snippets'
NeoBundle 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
NeoBundle 'ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim'
NeoBundle 'flazz/vim-colorschemes'

NeoBundle 'Shougo/vimshell', { 'rev' : '3787e5' }

call neobundle#end()

filetype plugin indent on

NeoBundleCheck



set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()

Plugin 'VundleVim/Vundle.vim'
Bundle 'YouCompleteMe'
Plugin 'tpope/vim-fugitive'
Plugin 'command-t'
Plugin 'rstacruz/sparkup', {'rtp': 'vim/'}

call vundle#end()            " required
filetype plugin indent on    " required

Plugin 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
filetype plugin on
set splitbelow
set splitright
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W><C-J>
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W><C-L>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
set foldmethod=indent
set foldlevel=99
nnoremap <space> za

let g:SimpylFold_docstring_preview=1
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.py
    \ set tabstop=4 |
    \ set softtabstop=4 |
    \ set shiftwidth=4 |
    \ set textwidth=79 |
    \ set expandtab |
    \ set autoindent |
    \ set fileformat=unix
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.js, *.html, *.css
    \ set tabstop=2 |
    \ set softtabstop=2 |
    \ set shiftwidth=2
Plugin 'vim-scripts/indentpython.vim'
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.py,*.pyw,*.c,*.h "match BadWhitespace /\s\+$/
set encoding=utf-8

let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_completion=1
map <leader>g  :YcmCompleter GoToDefinitionElseDeclaration<CR>




execute pathogen#infect()


Plugin 'vim-syntastic/syntastic'
Plugin 'nvie/vim-flake8'
let python_highlight_all=1

set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
set statusline+=%{SyntasticStatuslineFlag()}
set statusline+=%*

let g:syntastic_always_populate_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_auto_loc_list = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_open = 1
let g:syntastic_check_on_wq = 0


let g:syntastic_python_checkers = ['pylint']
let g:syntastic_php_checkers = ['php', 'phpcs', 'phpmd']
let g:syntastic_tex_checkers = ['lacheck', 'text/language_check']
let g:syntastic_aggregate_errors = 1
let g:syntastic_enable_perl_checker = 1


Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator' , { 'branch': 'stable'}
```

And my bundle dir is :

```
 ls -l .vim/bundle/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  6 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 15:12 command-t
drwxr-xr-x  6 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:23 ctrlp.vim
drwxr-xr-x  4 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 17:16 indentpython.vim
-rw-r--r--  1 mohsen mohsen  552 Sep 23 21:23 NeoBundle.lock
drwxr-xr-x  8 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:18 neobundle.vim
drwxr-xr-x  4 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:21 neosnippet-snippets
drwxr-xr-x 12 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:22 neosnippet.vim
drwxr-xr-x  7 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 17:09 SimpylFold
drwxr-xr-x  6 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 15:05 sparkup
drwxr-xr-x  8 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 22 20:46 syntastic
drwxr-xr-x  5 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:22 vim-colorschemes
drwxr-xr-x  5 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 24 16:26 vim-flake8
drwxr-xr-x  7 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 15:12 vim-fugitive
drwxr-xr-x  7 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 21:23 vimshell_3787e5
drwxr-xr-x  8 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 19 14:42 Vundle.vim
drwxr-xr-x  5 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 23 19:55 YCM-Generator
drwxr-xr-x 11 mohsen mohsen 4096 Sep 20 17:50 YouCompleteMe
```

When I run vim I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /home/mohsen/.vim/vimrc:
line  164:
E464: Ambiguous use of user-defined command: Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator' , { 'branch': 'stable'}
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

What's my problem?

Comment: you apparently use Vundle, Neobundle and pathogen and perhaps even vim-plug to load plugins. You should clean this up and decide one one single plugin manager to use. Or use the native package feature that comes with Vim 8

Comment: Christian is right, you should have a look at [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841) and [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9522/1841)

Comment: Is it problem if I use 2 or higher plugin manager?

Comment: You have just discovered it is @PersianGulf :-) You could make it work with some effort perhaps, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @PersianGulf Strictly speaking, no. But practically, yes, because you're unnecessarily overcomplicating things, which is the root of your issue in this question. You wouldn't use `pacman`, `yum` **and** `apt` to manage packages on your Linux install, right? :) Same thing here. Each plugin manager works toward the same goal, but does so in its own way. Having all 3 intermix simultaneously is begging for problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message comes from the last line of your vimrc:

```
Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator' , { 'branch': 'stable'}
```

This is a call to the `Plug` command of the [Vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) plugin manager. To work, this line should be surrounded by the following lines as it's stated [in the readme](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug#usage):

```
call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')
Plug 'rdnetto/YCM-Generator' , { 'branch': 'stable'}
call plug#end()
```

Now your *real* problem is that you try to use three or four different plugins managers: that is totally unnecessary. Instead you should have a read at our question [What is the difference between the vim plugin managers?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841), decide which plugin manager you want to use and use only this one for all of your plugins.

At a second reading of your vimrc: you have plugins that you're trying to install several time (i.e. `vim-fugitive`) I guess it means that you blindly copied the vimrc of other people and mixed them together without understanding every line. That is not a good idea (your question is the proof of what I'm saying). You would probably loose less time crafting your own vimrc to fit your own needs than debugging someone else's config.