# How to load vim-javascript using Vim 8 native package manager?

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, packages

I am long time Vim (Windows 10, gVim 8.1) user, happy as a clam with Vim 7. I have not used any of the plugin managers, just the one-off plugin from vim.org. I went looking for plugins to help with editing Javascript code (syntax highlighting, indenting, linting, etc.) and most folks seem to recommend [this](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript) one.

I am **not** interested in Git integration, auto updating it, sub-modules or any of that stuff. I created a `pack/<key>/start` folder and downloaded [this](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript/archive/master.zip) from Github.

What is the next step? Where should I unzip it in order to associate all the goodness in the package with `*.js` buffers automatically or manually using `set ft=javascript`?

Thanks

Comment: should be easy. Simply extract the folder below `pack/key/start` so that you have afterwards a new directory `pack/key/start/vim-javascript` which the usual vim plugin structure. After restarting Vim, the package should be automatically loaded.

Comment: FWIW the question I asked [there](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9522/1841) has different answers describing how to install a plugin with the package manager. Maybe that could be useful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the Vim8 package feature and how should I use it?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9522/what-is-the-vim8-package-feature-and-how-should-i-use-it)