# How does one install a VIM plugin without a plugin manager?

Tags: neovim, plugin-system, linux

I am **new** to vim, I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlR5gYd6um0) and wish to give it a good try for a month to see how I like it.

I want to add the NERDTree plugin to my vim, I'm actually using NeoVIM:

```
NVIM v0.4.4
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
```

I Googled and found [this article](https://opensource.com/article/20/2/how-install-vim-plugins). It seemed straightforward but when I followed the steps, it doesn't seem to work for me, so I guess I'm missing something.

```
~|⇒ ls ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start   
nerdtree
~|⇒ ls -l ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree
total 164
drwxr-xr-x 3 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 autoload
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwan jwan 30828 Feb 21 11:29 CHANGELOG.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwan jwan    26 Feb 21 11:29 _config.yml
drwxr-xr-x 2 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 doc
drwxr-xr-x 3 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 lib
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwan jwan   474 Feb 21 11:29 LICENCE
drwxr-xr-x 2 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 nerdtree_plugin
drwxr-xr-x 2 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 plugin
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwan jwan  8429 Feb 21 11:29 README.markdown
-rw-r--r-- 1 jwan jwan 87896 Feb 21 11:29 screenshot.png
drwxr-xr-x 2 jwan jwan  4096 Feb 21 11:29 syntax
```

According to the article, that should be all that I have to do! The article says:

> Now you can place Vim plugins in ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start, and they'll automatically load when you launch Vim.

That doesn't seem to happen for me! When I have vim open and I type `:NERDTree` I just get:

```
E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If not duplicates, at least related questions [How do I install a plugin in Vim/vi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/613/1841) and [What is the Vim8 package feature and how should I use it?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9522/1841). FWIW I created the same file hierarchy and cloned https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree in `start` and `:NERDTree` is available, maybe check `:messages` for any error message.

Comment: Thanks @statox, indeed, both are related. I read them before asking my question, sadly I was none the wiser. The first question is mostly about plugin managers. The second one is what I'm after but after following the steps I can't get it to work, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried with an orginal vim8 instance rather and neovim? And as I said in my edit in my previous comment, maybe check for error messages in `:messages`, also check if `:scriptnames` mentions NERDTree

Comment: `:messages` gives me what I had before, which is: `E492: Not an editor command: NERDTree`, but `:scriptnames` is [rather interesting](https://imgur.com/a/Ei9Ln66). Maybe in NeoVIM, plugins go somewhere different!

Comment: See `:help standard-path`. Also `:help vim-differences`.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thank you @D.BenKnoble, I'm really excited!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't deal with the hassle. So I just installed `neovim` and installed standalone `vim`. I figured most online articles and documentation will refer to standalone `vim` too.

Things worked straight away.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would just stick to pathogen until you get familiarized with how things work. I started moving things to the 'pack/yourname/start' one day and things started breaking. That being said I am working on a plugin and 'pack/myname/start' seems to work fine. Pack is a great way to separate your plugins. If you notice tpope plugins usually go in there.