# How do I install a package in Neovim without a package manager?

Tags: neovim

I would like to install a package in Neovim (nvim), but I don't want to use a package manager like [`vim-plug`](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug). I want to keep my configuration as minimal as possible, which is why I want to avoid a package manager.

In Vim 8.0, you can install a package simply by putting it under `~/.vim/pack/FOOBAR/start/`, replacing `FOOBAR` with any directory name you choose. Does Neovim support this? Does it support another method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Neovim, you can install plugins into `~/.config/nvim/pack/FOOBAR/start/` (replacing `FOOBAR` with any directory name you choose), similarly to how you can use [Vim 8.0's native support for packages](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9522/7244).

Alternatively, you can also install plugins into `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/FOOBAR/start/` (replacing `FOOBAR` with any directory name you choose).

To find the full list of places where you can put a package, run `:set packpath?` . You can install packages in the `pack/FOOBAR/start/` subdirectory of each one of these directories listed by that command, replacing `FOOBAR` with any directory name you like. (If you've [configured Neovim to load Vim configuration](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim), then you will probably find `~/.vim` in the list of directories, which means you can also put plugins in `~/.vim/pack/FOOBAR/start/` , just like for Vim.)