# How to update vim plugins with pathogen package manager?

Tags: plugin-system, plugin-pathogen

I'm searching for a way to update all my vim plugins with pathogen. I see this is simple in other package managers like Neobundle or vundle.

Please share a way to update all my plugins without having to use some hacky script that I haven't thought of yet to accomplish this.

Comment: If, and only if, you insist on not using a plugin manager (as the answers rightly suggest), there is a Linux tool called [myrepos](https://github.com/joeyh/myrepos) that allows you to update multiple repositories at once (you first have to register them once with `mr`, the just do `mr update` from your home folder when desired, to update all of them at once). Note that, with Vim 8, you may not even need pathogen at all (see `:h packages`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

pathogen manages the run time path of Vim.  It is not the same as vim-plug nor vundle.

The [differences between the vim plugin managers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-plugin-managers) has many good answers.  :-)

[How to use Tim Pope's Pathogen](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9970697) was created by romainl who has a lot of reputation on this site.  I hope that helps.

---

Answer (score 6):

Pathogen is not a plugin *manager* at all. Updating your plugins is *your* job and the best method depends entirely on how *you* installed those plugins.

If you want an actual plugin *manager*, try Neobundle, Vundle, Plug, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Pathogen will not manage (update, install, etc.) your plugins for you. You have to do that yourself.

And a good way to do that yourself is to install plugins simply by cloning their Git repos to the ~/.vim/bundle folder. Then you can update them with one-line loops. For example in Bash you could do this:

```
for i in ~/.vim/bundle/*; do git -C $i pull; done
```

And on Windows you could do this (assuming Git is in PATH):

```
for /d %i in (%userprofile%\.vim\bundle\*) do ( git -C "%i" pull )
```

If your plugins have submodules, you can also add `git -C "$i" submodule update --init --recursive` after the pull (on Windows change `$` to `%`).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers point out, Pathogen manipulates the Vim runtime directories rather than managing plugins.

I use Git to manage changes to my Vim configuration files (living in `~/.vim`). Each of my plugins (including Pathogen itself) is installed into `~/.vim/bundle` directory as Git sub-modules. This allows me to to use `git submodule` to pull in all changes
from the remote repository.

Change into the repository working directory:

```
cd ~/.vim
```

Ensure that each git sub-module has the `master` branch checked out:

```
git submodule foreach git checkout master
```

Ensure that the remote-tracking branch is set to the origin remote:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master
# git submodule foreach git config branch.master.remote origin
```

Update each sub-module:

```
git submodule foreach git pull
```