# Problems in installing vim-latex

Tags: plugin-vim-latex

I try to install [vim-latex](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download), a plugin for vim to edit latex file,
According to the download page

> > In step 3 of 4 :To install the included latex-suite.txt and latexhelp.txt files as vim help files, start vim and do the following:

```
helptags ~/.vim/doc
```

It promts

```
E150: Not a directory: ~/.vim/doc
```

Then I did

```
helptags ~/.vim/vim-latex-1.9.0/doc
```

nothing happened

> > Step 4 of 4: Done!
> >     Thats it! You are done! Now start editing a latex file in vim. Latex-Suite should start up automatically. You can do

```
:help latex-suite.txt
```

I got another error

```
E149: Sorry, no help for latex-suite.txt
```

I summarized the steps I did before

> > Step 1 of 4: Download and extract the archives

```
tar xvzf vim-latex-1.9.0.tar.gz -C ~/.vim
```

nothing wrong, there is one more file  `vim-latex-1.9.0.tar` under  `~/.vim`

> > Step 2 of 4: Set a few things in `.vimrc`

I copied the contents to my `.vimrc` file in a right way. 
there is no file named `tex.vim` under `~/.vim/ftplugin/` so I created one and copy the contents to my `tex.vim`

when I start editing `.tex` file, nothing paticular happened, so I guess I didn'd have  `vim-latex` installed. I don't know where I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've added the `vim-latex-1.9.0` directory as a subdirectory of your `.vim` directory. For a traditional installation, you should be adding the *contents* of the `vim-latex-1.9.0` directory to your `.vim` directory (merging the contents of any directories into the directories that already exist in `.vim`, if necessary.)

However, I'd strongly recommend you look into the more recent methods of installation, either Vim 8's `package` feature (or if you are still on Vim 7, [pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen)), or one of the [various plugin managers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-plugin-managers) that are available, which offer various advantages over the old method.