# How to update plugins in Neobundle

Tags: plugin-managers

I use NeoBundle for plugin manager but I am not sure how to update plugins. Do I have to update one by one? Or there any command to update plugins?

Comment: This would probably be clear from the documentation of NeoBundle. And if not, then why use NeoBundle and not one of the many other managers that work well? Also, Shougo, the author of NeoBundle, has created a newer and AFAIK better manager called dein.vim. See [here for a comparison of plugin managers](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/388/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-plugin-managers).

Answer (score 2):

From [`:h neobundle-usage`](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim/blob/master/doc/neobundle.txt#L73-L76):

> Run this command to update your bundled plugins:
>
> ```
> :NeoBundleUpdate
> ```