# Using pathogen, will allow me to exploit neovim capabilities when developing a plugin?

Tags: neovim, plugin-pathogen

I just finished reading [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/), and I am working right now with neovim
And I had a bulky config file with a lot of stuff, that really slowed down vim, when I was handling *heavy* searches, or dealing with *long* files, and now I switched to Neovim, and the same config, flys which is cool.

Now, I wanted to put my configs into separate plugins for my self, and also expand my functionality with some plugins written in Python. But I haven't found any concrete hint (or at least to my understanding) that

1. Pathogen works well on Neovim?
2. It keeps in different threads all the processes, so It won't hit performance having external plugins?
3. I don't understand the excitement about Plugs, should I consider it?

I like pathogen because It as simple as it can get, and It's not intrusive in your config files.

Could anyone help me out, or point me in the right direction with this?

Comment: 1. Pathogen is so minimal that I'd be amazed if it didn't work in Neovim. 2. I couldn't parse that. Processes in threads? O.o 3. What's Plugs? Do you mean [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug)? Or https://github.com/neoclide/plug.nvim?

Comment: 2. well, supposedly each plugin is each own process in nvim, so, I used the thread word in that sense, the question could be rephrase as "With pathogen, would I still be able to exploit the asynchronous control ?  
3. yes vim-plug, I don't really get what is the benefit, beside the managing the plugins, and easy install, but is there something else from it? I like pathogen, because of it;s simplicity.

Comment: The third benefit is lazy-loading - it can load a plugin only for files which satisfy some condition. But managing and easy installation are probably the main reason why people who use something other than Pathogen don't use Pathogen. If those aren't important to you, well, :shrug:

Comment: About pathogen working with neovim, there are several posts but the first google result I found is [this old reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/2lfy91/is_pathogen_supported_in_neovim/) where people say it works fine, which is not surprising as muru said. For your question about vim-plug, you might be interested by [this question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/388/1841). Finally about your second question it depends on the implementation of the plugin: each plugin maintainer can decide to use an asynchronous behavior or not when they think it's necessary.